# Send Thank you email with phpmailer

Tags: php, forms, email, smtp, phpmailer

i have a phpmailer form that is sending email perfectly fine however a I would like to send 2 emails per form submit. The first email should be the form field values to myself. Thsi works as expected. I am having toruble finding any documentation that would allow me to send a second email to the person who submitted the form to say thanks for contacting us we will be in touch shortly. I basically would like to send a second email to the value you `$_POST['email']` with "Thank You" as the contents.

The form code (without any thank you email):

```
            require 'library/extensions/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

            $mail = new PHPMailer;


            $strMessage = "";

            //Only action if the form has been submitted
            if(isset($_POST['submit-contact-new'])) {
                //Validate the fields again, because not everyone has Javascript, including bots

                if (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] !== "" &&
                    isset($_POST['surname']) && $_POST['surname'] !== "" &&
                    isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] !== "" &&
                    isset($_POST['phone']) && $_POST['phone'] !== "" &&
                    isset($_POST['comment']) && $_POST['comment'] !== "") {





            //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'mail.domain.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = 'noreply@domain.com';                 // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'passwd';                           // SMTP password

            $mail->From = 'noreply@domain.com';
            $mail->FromName = 'Domain';
            $mail->addAddress('staffmember@domain.com', 'First Last');     // Add a recipient
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

            $mail->Subject = 'Domain Form Enquiry';
            $mail->Body    = '
            <html>
                            <body>
                                <h1>Domain Website Enquiry</h1>
                                <p>Information on form was:</p>
                                <p><strong>Name</strong>: '.$_POST['name'].'</p>
                                <p><strong>Surname</strong>: '.$_POST['surname'].'</p>
                                <p><strong>Email</strong>: '.$_POST['email'].'</p>
                                <p><strong>Phone</strong>: '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>
                                <p><strong>Enquiry</strong>: '.$_POST['comment'].'</p>
                            </body>
                        </html>
                        ';

            if(!$mail->send()) {

               //Finally redirect
                    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '?message='.$strMessage) ;
            } else {
              //Finally redirect
                    header('Location: http://domain.com/thank-you?location='.$strLocation) ;
            }

            } else {

                     //Something is wrong, so work out what
                    if (!isset($_POST['name']) || $_POST['name'] === "") $strMessage .= "<li>Name must be entered</li>";
                    if (!isset($_POST['surname']) || $_POST['surname'] === "") $strMessage .= "<li>Surname must be entered</li>";
                    if (isset($_POST['surname']) && isset($_POST['surname']) && $_POST['name'] === $_POST['surname']) $strMessage .= "<li>Name and Surname must be different</li>";
                    if (!isset($_POST['phone']) || $_POST['phone'] === "") $strMessage .= "<li>Phone Number must be entered</li>";
                    if (!isset($_POST['email']) || $_POST['email'] === "") $strMessage .= "<li>Email must be entered</li>";
                    if (!isset($_POST['comment']) || $_POST['comment'] === "") $strMessage .= "<li>An enquiry must be entered</li>";

                    if ($strMessage !== "") $strMessage = "<ul>" . $strMessage . "</ul>";

                    //Finally redirect
                    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '?message='.$strMessage) ;
                    exit();
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Add this **$mail->AddAddress($_POST['email']);** after **$mail->addAddress('staffmember@domain.com', 'First Last');**

Comment: @Norman This would send the same body content to both parties whereas I would like to send different body content to both. Thank you

Comment: then wrap your code in function and pass 2 parameters 1 for email and second for message body. just call your function here passing both different email and message body using parameters. and then Enjoy :)

Comment: Would you be able to show how that would work? I am not that proficent with php. Sorry. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue I simply put another instance within this form action and ran phpmailer twice. This enabled me to set seperate body contents and reciepts using the same post content.

```
<?php
    require 'library/extensions/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $strMessage = "";
    //Only action if the form has been submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit-contact-new'])) {

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mail.domain.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'noreply@domain.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'passwd';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->From = 'noreply@domain.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'Domain';
    $mail->addAddress('staff@domain.com', 'Staff Name');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Domain Form Enquiry';
    $mail->Body    = '
    <html>
                    <body>
                        <h1>Domain Website Enquiry</h1>
                        <p>Information on form was:</p>
                        <p><strong>Name</strong>: '.$_POST['name'].'</p>
                        <p><strong>Surname</strong>: '.$_POST['surname'].'</p>
                        <p><strong>Email</strong>: '.$_POST['email'].'</p>
                        <p><strong>Phone</strong>: '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>
                        <p><strong>Enquiry</strong>: '.$_POST['comment'].'</p>
                    </body>
                </html>
                ';
    if(!$mail->send()) {
       //Finally redirect
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      //Finally redirect
            header('Location: http://domain.com/thank-you?location='.$strLocation) ;
    }
    }
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $strMessage = "";
    //Only action if the form has been submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit-contact-new'])) {

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mail.domain.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'noreply@rdomain.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->From = 'noreply@domain.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'Domain';
    $mail->addAddress(''.$_POST['email'].'');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Thank you for contacting Domain';
    $mail->Body    = 'Thanks for getting in touch. Your message has been received and will be processed as soon as possible.';
    if(!$mail->send()) {
       //Finally redirect
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      //Finally redirect
            header('Location: http://domain.com/thank-you?location='.$strLocation) ;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You can do that, but it's more efficient to call clearAllRecipients, change whatever other bits you want and just call send again, all using the same PHPMailer instance.